# Singly linked lists data structure in c: linking a list

Tags: c, singly-linked-list

I'm trying to select a random node in a linked list. My idea is relink the list n-times so that the head changes every time n-times is a different value. So ex: list contains he->needs->some->milk. Starting from milk, linking this as the head of another lists node, for n-times=2, the head will become needs. If n-times=3, the head becomes he. As a function, the parameters to do this are a list and a random number.
My idea is written below:

```
typedef  struct Stops

 {

    char name[51];

    struct Stops *nxt;
  }Stops;

     Stops *relinking (Stops *alist_torelink, int rndtimes)

  {

    int linkcnt=0; //to count how many times it's been linked, i.e how many links//

    Stops *leknd=NULL;


    while(  alist_torelink!=NULL  && linkcnt < rndtimes  )
    {  
        leknd= (Stops*) malloc(sizeof(Stops));
        strcpy(leknd->name, alist_torelink->name);
        leknd->nxt=alist_torelink;
        linkcnt++;
        if(alist_torelink==NULL) 
        {alist_torelink=leknd;} //so if it reaches the end of the original list, it starts back at the head of the list being relinked and continues. this will mean the loop exits when linkcnt=rndtimes-1//
        alist_torelink=alist_torelink->nxt;
    } return leknd;

     }
```

this works effectively enough to get a random head, however there are issues with the code i do not see. Like with an original list with 5 elements, if a new list is created as 
Stops *newlist= relinking(original, 4), the behavior of the function, I do not understand, i can only see the newlist created is

Comment: @awdbutahdagreyt Do you need to create one more list from the original list or you need just to relink anew nodes in the original list without creating one more list?

Comment: I can't modify the original so yes, I'd need to create new nodes from the original.

Comment: And what is the problem?

Comment: There is a (even relatively efficient) way to just select a random node from a list without knowing the length of the list in advance, but your current statement of the problem is too vague to tell if it is adequate to your needs.

Comment: selecting a random node from a list is exactly what i want to do. Everything above is the way i thought to do that.

Comment: I really cannot say what the problem is. I am unfamiliar with linked lists as I've only had 2 weeks learning this. The function doesn't work with any value for rndtimes ex: if rndtimes=7 and the original list has 8 elements, the newlist created only has 2 elements, with both elements being the same
i.e in the 1st list: I->want->sleep->with->dreams->that->are->lucid
the list created has lucid->lucid->are as its elements
with rndtimes=6 the list created is lucid->are->that->that
with rndtimes=8 the list= lucid->lucid

Answer (score 2):

There is generic algorithm for selecting an item with uniform probability from a list whose length is not known in advance, and linked list structures are generally good candidates for it.

It works like this

```
If empty(list)
   return a non-selection/throw an error
currentItem := firstItem
i := 1
interimSelection := currentItem
While (there is another item)
   i := i + 1
   currentItem := next(currentItem)
   if ( random() <= 1/i )
      interimSelection := currentItem
Return interimSelection
```

Here `random()` return a random value on the range [0,1), so the conditional says "select the current item with probability 1/i.

The algorithm runs in O(n) time for n the number of items in the list, and requires constant space beyond that occupied by the list itself.

---

To convince yourself that this procedure does what you want (give you a 1/n chance of getting each and every item in a list of n items), consider what must happen for the mth  item to be selected:

1. The mth item must be selected when it is reached (`P = 1/m`).
2. Every subsequent item must *not* be selected (`P = (k-1)/k`).

So that the total probability for the mth node is

```
P_m = (1/m) * prod_{k=m+1}^{n} (k-1)/k .
```

But (k-1) for the first term in the product is m+1-1=m, so you can cancel the numerator of the first product term with the denominator of the original term. And the numerator of the second product tem cancels the denominator of the first. And so on until the final result is 1/n.

---

Implementing it in c calls for you to translate the pseudo-statements in my sketch above into code.

Here are some suggestions

- The list is empty if the head is `NULL`
- Assigning and returning items is done by assigning and returning pointers
- Testing for the presence of another item means examining the `next` member of the current node.
- The usual functions for drawing random values return integer values in some range [0,N), instead of reals in [0,1) and the behavior of integer arithematic in c is such that the way I wrote the selection conditional is less that optimal; you should transform it into a more idiomatic form.

Answer (score 0):

```
K *copymake(K *alist)
{
    K *one= (K*) malloc(sizeof(K));

    strcpy(one->name, alist->name);
    one->nodenext=alist;
    one=alist;
    return one;
}
    K *relinking(K *alist, int rNdnum)
    {
    K *one=copymake(alist);
        while(rNdnum>0)
        {
            alist=alist->nodenext;
            rNdnum--;
            if(alist==NULL)
            {
                alist=one;
            }
        }return alist;
    }
```

relinking: traverse the list starting from the head. Do this n-times. n-times=rNdnum. The head changes. If the list is null, set it to another list, which is just a copy of the original. This way, if rNdnum > number of nodes, the next node in the traversal does not equal NULL, but the another node of the list.